# How to set label backColor on gradient background panel

Tags: c#, label, panel

Background Color of the panel control is set to color gradient.

and i want to set same panel backcolor and label pack color

my code is same below

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.panel1.Width, this.panel1.Height), Color.Black, Color.Black, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
            ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
            cb.Colors = new Color[] { Color.Black, Color.White };
            cb.Positions = new Single[] { 0.0F, 1.0F };
            lgb.InterpolationColors = cb;

            g.FillRectangle(lgb, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.panel1.Width, this.panel1.Height));
            label1.Parent = panel1;
            label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            lgb.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();

        }
```

Which part was wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the line below:

```
Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
```

Change it to:

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
```

And you can also put the following codes in the constructor (to avoid reassigning whenever panel is `Invalidated`):

```
label1.Parent = panel1;
label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```